# Purged Network-Manager and now I can't download it because I don't have any internet connection

Tags: 12.04, network-manager

First off, I'm new to Linux - I have Windows 7 installed in my laptop. I thought of installing Ubuntu 12.04 and I used the option "install alongside windows". So every thing went down good except Network Manager icon did not show the wireless connection that I get in Win 7. I have gone through almost all forums. I followed some instruction (terminal commands) but i just came to know that those command require internet connection. So, its no benefit. And just recently i removed network manager using the code

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

for some stupid reasons (don't ask) and now i can't re-install using the code

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

I  guess that code also needs internet connection. I am FRUSTATED out of my mind. Need help badly.

Comment: I commonly have this problem with my laptop when installing Ubuntu fresh. It equals effort, but finding a wired connection solves the problem. I check 'Additional Drivers' to tick the driver available for my network card.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you could find a wired connection and connect your laptop to that and then reinstall the network manager.

After that, you should check the 'Additional Drivers' to see if you can find the drivers available there for your network card - it requires a network connection as well to download those and requires you to reboot after installing them.

If you have no luck with getting a wired internet connection, you might be better off re-installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Re-installing is a last ditched attempt to start over with the Network-Manager installed. But yes, it really isn't a solution to anything.